# Automatically Update Formula in Google Sheets so that it calculates difference between two adjacent columns with weekly updated values

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have the following row indicating attendance at team meetings:

```
Employee  Wk 3/7    Wk of 3/14  Wk of 3/21  Wk of 3/28  Wk of 4/4   
John
```

The columns  Wk [Date] are updated every Monday Morning. Next Monday I will see something like this

```
Employee  Wk 3/7    Wk of 3/14  Wk of 3/21  Wk of 3/28  Wk of 4/4   
John        4
```

John was present to four meetings in the week of 3/7

The week after that I'll see something like this:

```
Employee  Wk 3/7    Wk of 3/14  Wk of 3/21  Wk of 3/28  Wk of 4/4   
John        4        5
```

John was present 5 meetings on week of 3/14.

I am creating a column next to Employee John as such:

```
  A                 B               C         D         E           F
1 Employee  Change from last Week Wk 3/7    Wk of 3/14  Wk of 3/21  Wk of 3/28  Wk of 4/4   
John                                 4        5
```

The change from next week cell would have the following Google Sheets formula:

```
=if(D1<C1, "Negative Attendance Trend", "")
```

Every Monday the neighboring column is updated with information pertaining to attendance for that week. I don't want to have to go in every single Monday morning and tweak the formula to  read as follows

```
=if(E1<D1, "Negative Attendance Trend", "")
```

and then

```
=if(F1<E1, "Negative Attendance Trend", "")
```

I'd like to move the the formula automatically move one column to the right every single week when a new value appears in the week of ** column and subtract that attendance from the value in the column immediately preceding to its left.

For example:

```
=if([Most Recent Full Week's Attendance] <[The second most Recent Full Week's Attendance], "Negative Change", "")
```

or still

```
=if([Most Recent Full Week's Attendance] > [The second most Recent Full Week's Attendance], "Positive Attendance Trend", "")
```

I have attempted to use a dynamic Google Sheets array only to get stuck there and not know to move forward to have the automatic recalculation occur as the Week Column gets populated each week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update2**

### **Script**

The best solution could be using the script.

Go to Tools > Script Editor, and paste this code in there:

```
function LastTwoDiff(Arr) {
  var Response = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < Arr.length; i++) {
      var cube = Arr[i];
      for(var j = cube.length-1; j >=0; j--) {
        if (cube[j] !== '') {
          Response.push(cube[j]-cube[j-1]);
          break;
      }
    }
  }
return Response;  
}
```

Then it could be used as usual formula:

```
=LastTwoDiff(C2:AB3)
```

It'll populate values and paste calculated array with the difference between:

1. last found cell from the right (column) where value <> ''
2. Previous left cell

All you need to complete is paste this formula in `B2`:

```
=if(LastTwoDiff(C2:BD4)>0,"","Negative...")
```

Please, [look at example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZW7p1bTqGs-CvnnI4yeBdJKgkdVbGNmrTzRr8_Q_SyM/edit?usp=sharing)

But if you still need only no script solution, go further.

---

### **Simple Formula**

This formula can be used, but it is to be copied down:

```
=if(INDEX(A2:H2,1,ArrayFormula(max(--(C2:H2>0)*column(C2:H2))))<INDEX(A2:H2,1,ArrayFormula(max(--(C2:H2>0)*column(C2:H2)))-1), "Negative Attendance Trend", "")
```

The result is:

[image]

Formula is entered in cell `B2`, then I'd copied it to `B2:B6`. When new data is added, formula acts correctly. [Example File](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BO9_zEQYbMpuPCv3dTNS4ro8p6VFzZNOyaD5eyYoInY/edit?usp=sharing). Formula gives `#REF!` if only one column has data, so I suggest using `IFERROR`

Or this formula will do the same:

```
=if(QUERY({ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(C2:H2))),TRANSPOSE(C2:H2)},"select Col2 where Col2 > 0 order by Col1 desc limit 1")<QUERY({ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(C2:H2))),TRANSPOSE(C2:H2)},"select Col2 where Col2 > 0 order by Col1 desc limit 1 offset 1"), "Negative Attendance Trend", "")
```

---

### **Array Formula**

This formula is not elegant, but it populates automatically:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(MMULT(ArrayFormula(C2:H6*--(if(row(C2:H6),COLUMN(C2:H6))=(sort(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(if(COLUMN(C2:H6),ROW(C2:H6))&"."&if(row(C2:H6),COLUMN(C2:H6))*(C2:H6<>"")&"|"),"|")),"order by Col1 desc skipping "&COLUMNS(C1:H1)))-INT(sort(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(if(COLUMN(C2:H6),ROW(C2:H6))&"."&if(row(C2:H6),COLUMN(C2:H6))*(C2:H6<>"")&"|"),"|")),"order by Col1 desc skipping "&COLUMNS(if(COLUMN(C2:H6),ROW(C2:H6)))))))*10 -1)),TRANSPOSE(ArrayFormula(COLUMN(C1:H1)^0)))>MMULT(ArrayFormula(C2:H6*--(if(row(C2:H6),COLUMN(C2:H6))=(sort(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(if(COLUMN(C2:H6),ROW(C2:H6))&"."&if(row(C2:H6),COLUMN(C2:H6))*(C2:H6<>"")&"|"),"|")),"order by Col1 desc skipping "&COLUMNS(C1:H1)))-INT(sort(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(if(COLUMN(C2:H6),ROW(C2:H6))&"."&if(row(C2:H6),COLUMN(C2:H6))*(C2:H6<>"")&"|"),"|")),"order by Col1 desc skipping "&COLUMNS(if(COLUMN(C2:H6),ROW(C2:H6)))))))*10)),TRANSPOSE(ArrayFormula(COLUMN(C1:H1)^0))),"Negative Attendance Trend",""))
```

It is placed in cell `B2` in [our example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BO9_zEQYbMpuPCv3dTNS4ro8p6VFzZNOyaD5eyYoInY/edit#gid=1123354914).

**Update1**

The formula above works only for small amount of columns (<10). So I fixed it and got final huge arrayFormula:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(MMULT(ArrayFormula(C2:AO4*--(if(row(C2:AO4),COLUMN(C2:AO4))=ROUNDUP((sort(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(if(COLUMN(C2:AO4),ROW(C2:AO4))&"."&text(if(row(C2:AO4),COLUMN(C2:AO4))*(C2:AO4<>""),"000")&"|"),"|")),"order by Col1 desc skipping "&COLUMNS(C2:AO4)))-INT(sort(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(if(COLUMN(C2:AO4),ROW(C2:AO4))&"."&text(if(row(C2:AO4),COLUMN(C2:AO4))*(C2:AO4<>""),"000")&"|"),"|")),"order by Col1 desc skipping "&COLUMNS(if(COLUMN(C2:AO4),ROW(C2:AO4)))))))*1000 -1))),TRANSPOSE(ArrayFormula(COLUMN(C2:AO4)^0)))>MMULT(ArrayFormula(C2:AO4*--(if(row(C2:AO4),COLUMN(C2:AO4))=ROUNDUP((sort(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(if(COLUMN(C2:AO4),ROW(C2:AO4))&"."&text(if(row(C2:AO4),COLUMN(C2:AO4))*(C2:AO4<>""),"000")&"|"),"|")),"order by Col1 desc skipping "&COLUMNS(C2:AO4)))-INT(sort(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(if(COLUMN(C2:AO4),ROW(C2:AO4))&"."&text(if(row(C2:AO4),COLUMN(C2:AO4))*(C2:AO4<>""),"000")&"|"),"|")),"order by Col1 desc skipping "&COLUMNS(if(COLUMN(C2:AO4),ROW(C2:AO4)))))))*1000))),TRANSPOSE(ArrayFormula(COLUMN(C2:AO4)^0))),"Negative Attendance Trend",""))
```

[Link to final workbook](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sI5xBr7V_iAWI5_V4LnztWs4X519wWxAh_SAzThJ8RI/edit?usp=sharing)

---

Comment: I'm not sure I understand entirely how to implement the code. In google sheets, I have attempted to do the [following] (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UGoK6C4GXisS-dDTONL2zjW-DPc0qqB92L68T2Qu2nc/edit?usp=sharing). I am not sure how to incorporate Array formula into this equation in Google Sheets or what it means exactly that a formula is to "be copied down". Just because there are no values in columns AB, AC, and AD doesn't mean that NA is the proper value to bring back. It should just find the attendance pattern of anything that is filled in with values (column AA for example).

Comment: I've added a script solution. I think, in some cases even if it could be done with formulas, the best way would be to use script. Please try and hope it helps.